# Method Chaining: mutable vs immutable php objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to understand why in the code below, both variations are valid:

1. `$draws = $draws->where('domain_id', $id);` and
2. `$draws->where('domain_id', $id);` (without reassigning the variable `$draw`)

```
    $draws = Draw::query();

    if ($condition)
        $draws->where('domain_id', $id); // <-- I used to call $draws = $draws->where('domain_id', $id);

    $draws = $draws->paginate(10);
```

I was under the assumption that I always had to reassign the variable `$draws` to make it work.

In Laravel, when don't I need to reassign the variable?

Comment: Since PHP 5 objects are passed by reference as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to mention the difference between `Mutable` and `Immutable` objects here.

#### Mutable objects

The `QueryBuilder` instance is a `Mutable` object (like many other, if not most PHP objects). This means that when you call something like:

```php
$query->where('status', 1);
```

The `$query` object will be updated with the data you passed to it. In other words, the `$this` context within that QueryBuilder object is continuously updated. So the `$query = $query->where('admin', 1)` is superfluous.

It's the same reason why the below function works:

```php
$query->whereHas('user', function(Builder $query) {
    $query->where('admin', 1);
});
```

There is no need to call `return` in that closure function.

#### Immutable objects

In comparison, you have for instance `Carbon` available in your Laravel projects. This is a datetime package which makes handling with dates and formats much easier. It is basically a wrapper around `DateTime` OR `DateTimeImmutable`.

As noted [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php), the `DateTimeImmutable` basically returns a new object for each function you call on it, so:

```php
$date = CarbonImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-02-21');
$newDate = $date->addMonth();

// $date does still equal `2020-02-21`.
// $newDate does now equal `2020-03-21`.
```

So the assignment to `$newDate` is actually required here (because else your `addMonth()` result is useless).

whereas the `Carbon` class is mutable:

```php
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-02-21');
$newDate = $date->addMonth(1);

// $date does now equal `2020-03-21`.
// $newDate does now equal `2020-03-21`.
// In fact, $date === $newDate
```

Both varieties have their strengths. You just have to keep it in mind when you're passing around these objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer! Is there an easy to find out which type of object is Mutable vs Immutable besides doing trial and error?

Comment: Only way is to look at the source code. But usually anything that has a `->setXXX()` method is a mutable object otherwise it wouldnt make much sense to name it that way. By far most objects are regular mutable PHP objects. Having an immutable resource is rare though and afaik the only thing that has it is `DateTimeImmutable`. For instance it wouldnt have much use to have an immutable `$response` variable in your Laravel controller

Answer (score 2):

**The reason why method chaining can be used is because it returns $this**

When you call `$draws->where('domain_id', $id);`

It will execute `where()` to save the query information in `$wheres` and return `$this`

Take a look at the snippet of where()

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    // something here

    // Now that we are working with just a simple query we can put the elements
    // in our array and add the query binding to our array of bindings that
    // will be bound to each SQL statements when it is finally executed.
    $this-> wheres[] = compact(
        'type', 'column', 'operator', 'value', 'boolean'
    );

    // something here

    return $this;
}
```

After that you call `$draws->paginate(10);`

It will generate query results and paginate according to the conditions in `$wheres`

There is no need to reassign the variable.